# PHP isset for GET variable in ternary operator

Tags: php, html

I have a `<select>` field and I want to have the appropriate `<option>` selected based on what the GET value is
So I have used a ternary statement to output a `selected` attribute like so:

```
<select name="data" id="data">
    <option value="1" <?php echo $_GET['data'] == '1' ? 'selected' : '' ; ?>>One</option>
    <option value="2" <?php echo $_GET['data'] == '2' ? 'selected' : '' ; ?>>Two</option>
    <option value="3" <?php echo $_GET['data'] == '3' ? 'selected' : '' ; ?>>Three</option>
</select>
```

The problem is, the when the page is first loaded there is no `$_GET` array so I get a php error in my select box:

> Notice:  Undefined index: data in...

So I tried using `isset` to first check if the array is set before checking if the value matches:

```
    <option value="1" <?php echo isset($_GET) && $_GET['data'] == '1' ? 'selected' : '' ; ?>>One</option>
```

This returns the same error.

What is the best way to concisely handle this error and achieve what I'm after?

Comment: $_GET is always set! you need to check the parameter  with isset($_GET['data'])

Comment: @Waygood right you are. post as answer and I shall accept.

Comment: Your accepted answer is good. For the first iteration only, and causes repetition.

Comment: @harryg I still think my answer is better ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
<option value="1" <?php echo ( isset($_GET['data']) && $_GET['data'] == '1') ? 'selected' : '' ;?> >One</option>
```

Comment: Any reason to downvote it..??

Comment: Not sure, although perhaps it violates the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)?

Comment: I have talked about the condition only not for the entire options..just its a refernce for ternary condition @Jimbo

Comment: Well the OP needed an answer for the entire list of options - are you suggesting that your answer isn't aimed at this?

Comment: Iam saying he had a problem with the ternary condition and I rectified it...

Comment: see this What is the best way to concisely handle this error and achieve what I'm after? at the question

Comment: Hey it's just my opinion, I didn't downvote.

Comment: No iam talking about the one who done this

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
<option value="1" <?php echo isset($_GET['data']) ? ($_GET['data'] == '1' ? 'selected' : '') : ''; ?>>One</option>
```

Comment: Works but not the most efficient or readable. Nested ternary statements is something I want to avoid

Answer (score 3):

You could utilise a `for` loop, and only print out the `$selected` variable when your requirement is true. This will save you repeating yourself.

```
<select name="data" id="data">
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) { ?>
        <?php $selected = (isset($_GET['data']) && $_GET['data'] === $i) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>
        <option value="<?=$i?>" <?=$selected?>><?=$i?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

*Note: I use PHP 5.4, so can legitimately use PHP short echo's which, in my opinion, are much nicer in views / templates*

If you want to display text for numbers and don't want to do it manually, using an array, you can check out Pear's [Numbers_Words](http://pear.php.net/package-info.php?package=Numbers_Words) package.

Comment: This would usually be the route I be take but seeing as I only have 3 `<options>` I felt constructing an array and using a `for` loop would be overkill and make the code less readable. Fair answer though. (I'd also prefer a `foreach` loop in this instance as it doesn't require knowing the length of the array and the element keys - my data isn't actually numbers).

Comment: Only reason I didn't suggest a `foreach()` is because you would need something to iterate around, and you didn't have that something ;) But cool. Something similar to this to prevent code duplication is always a good step forward.